# Custom malloc in JNI/shared library

Tags: java, c, linker, java-native-interface

I would like to use my own malloc implementation in a shared library, which will be loaded into the JVM. It contains some Java Native Code functions. I have the following questions:

(1) I want to replace malloc/free/calloc etc. in my C code, but the JVM should still work with the real malloc(). However, I found several references stating that each function symbol is resolved to one address for the entire application, so, can this work at all?

(2) If the shared library is linked against another library, will the second library use my malloc as well?

It is okay if all of this works on Linux only, no portability required.

PS: I thought about using a #define malloc my_malloc when I compile the library, however, this would not affect libraries that are loaded by the library.

Comment: Your JNI allocator and the JVM allocator should not be assumed as the same. It is *possible* the are if they use the same shared C-runtime, but it doesn't matter because at no time do you ever `free()` something a JVM allocated nor do you `malloc()` something the JVM frees. A properly written JNI uses memory management cross-JNI-to-JVM through the JVM environment API.

Comment: Would you be looking for something like [Electric Fence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_Fence) by any chance? We can choose which library gets linked with what. JVM or no JVM